# How to pass generic parameters in Java

Tags: java, generics, parameters

In Java I have two classes:

```
Class A
{
  public String ID;
  public Object Name;
}

Class B
{
  public String ID;
  public Object Name;
}
```

I want to have a method where I can pass it either a Class A or B object:

```
public void SomeMethod(???  arg)
{
  String id = arg.ID;
  Object name= arg.Name;
}
```

Is it possible to pass an object of either class A or B to this method? If so, how is the method's signature written?

The only solution I can think of is to create an interface that both Class A and B implements containing get and set methods to set the fields ID and Name. Then the method's signature would be a parameter whose type is the interface. I was hoping that maybe there is a simpler way, possibly with generics?

Comment: You have stated the best solution. creating the interface.  There is a more complex way, with reflection, but that would be pretty horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need generic types. Simple inheritance will do the job

```
abstract class Base {
  public String ID;
  public Object Name;
}

class A extends Base {
}

class B extends Base {
}

public void SomeMethod(Base arg)
{
  String id = arg.ID;
  Object name= arg.Name;
}
```

Comment: Andrew Fielden's solution is the closest but if I go with this solution. Assume I extend A as you've indicated with the Base class:

    public class C
    {
      public int Age;
    }
 
    A a = new A();
    a.Name = new C(); // I assign a class C to Name.

How do I access Age?

    a.Name.Age = 100; //This is not allowed.

Comment: You access the Age member by using a cast ((C)a.Name).Age

Answer (score 4):

You are correct with needing to use an interface (or an abstract class) with the appropriate method signatures. To java the two class are different with nothing (beside Object) in common. You need to create a class hierarchy refelecting the commonality between them.

Comment: Are you saying that it is not possible with generics?

Comment: Yes. Once you have a class hierarchy then you could use generics but then it would be over kill in this case.

Comment: With generics, you would in effect have to wrap another object around them so that you could have Container<A> and Container<B>, which I believe would not provide you with any benefit, unless they shared a common interface or abstract parent. This is because otherwise, you can only work with them as an instance of Object

Answer (score 2):

Use [method overloading](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

```
public void SomeMethod(A arg)
{
  String id = arg.ID;
  Object name= arg.Name;
}

public void SomeMethod(B arg)
{
  String id = arg.ID;
  Object name= arg.Name;
}
```

You could make an interface and have `A` and `B` implement it. It really depends on your application. For small programs, I would just stick with method overloading since it just introduces unnecessary abstraction into your program.

For larger applications where extensibility is a priority, you may want to consider using an interface. Suppose later on you want to write classes `C` and `D` which also have `SomeMethod()`. Using an interface makes it so that you don't have to go through your entire code and overload appropriate methods over and over again.

If you know for sure that `A` and `B` are the end of the story, then there's no need to make an interface.

**EDIT:** If there's a lot of code to be duplicated, then make a helper method:

```
public void SomeMethod(A arg)
{
  HelpMePlease( arg.ID, arg.Name );
}

public void SomeMethod(B arg)
{
  HelpMePlease( arg.ID, arg.Name );
}

private void HelpMePlease( String id, Object name ) {
  // 1000 lines of code here
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm aware of overloading but are you aware that you have just duplicated the code? Two lines is nothing, but if you have a lot of code, overloading doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Polaris since class A and B aren't implementing an interface there is no connection between them.

Comment: So if class A or B has 50 fields (properties), you want to pass 50 parameters to HelpMePlease?? Ah, no thanks.

Comment: @Polaris431: Make an interface then. Next time, please mention in your OP what you've already tried/considered and why they don't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are intended to improve type safety during compilation.

What you are asking about seems to be something akin to C++ *concepts* or various other languages' *duck typing*.

In Java, if some sequence of operations need to be performed on two disparate types, you need to introduce an interface or resort to scripting/reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Define two interfaces, hasID and hasName, and then:

```
public class MyClass<A extends hasID & hasName>{
    public void SomeMethod(A object) {
        String id = object.getID();
        Object name= object.getName();
    }
}
```

Where getID and getName are defined on their respctive interfaces.

Comment: Actually, I made up that sample code for illustration purposes. In reality, there could be 50 or more properties, so I am not going to create 50 interfaces. Is there no way this can be done with generics?

Comment: If you have two classes both with 50 or more properties in common then I think creating 50 interfaces is the least of your problems.